# How to create dates from date components in SQL (T-SQL)?

Tags: sql, t-sql

How can I construct native date data type values in SQL (T-SQL)?

I've added some examples, but please provide your own. My examples assume that the month and year are being stored (or are readily available) as integer values, but maybe *your* example will assume that the day and the month (or whatever) are stored as text. I can't see the future; surprise me.

Comment: There are other questions that are really the same as this, but in the interests of providing as many search results for different *wordings* of what are really the same question, I created this question (instead of, as I initially started to, editing the title of another question).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why, with input data as strings one of the most obvious (and therefore hardly surprising, sorry) solutions would be:

```
SELECT
  mydate = CAST([year] + RIGHT('0' + [month], 2) + '01' AS datetime)
                                           /* or 'AS date' in SQL Server 2008+ */
FROM (
  SELECT [month] = '2',  [year] = '2011' UNION ALL
  SELECT [month] = '03', [year] = '2011' UNION ALL
  SELECT [month] = '5',  [year] = '2011' UNION ALL
  SELECT [month] = '12', [year] = '2011' UNION ALL
  SELECT [month] = '8',  [year] = '2084' UNION ALL
  SELECT [month] = '1',  [year] = '1940'
) x;
```

Comment: This is just a caching strategy for programming algorithms (i.e. programmers)!

Comment: +1 The point being that T-SQL will always convert strings in the form 'yyyymmdd' correctly... no matter what you're using as a custom date format. (Assuming of course the string is a valid date.)

Comment: In the interests of 'accepting an answer' for all of my questions, I've chosen this as 'the winner'. Congratulations!

Answer (score 20):

```
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(@Year, @Month, @Day)
```

([From SQL Server 2012](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/peterl/archive/2011/07/13/a-glance-at-sql-server-denali-ctp3-datefromparts.aspx))

Comment: @Augustas - The answer only contains two lines. One of them states `(From SQL Server 2012)` so I would have thought that is clear...

Comment: OK but you might get exception for 29/02. I am using DATEADD(DAY, @ Day - 1,DATEFROMPARTS(@ Year, @ month, 1))

Comment: @ČikićNenad yes you would  get an exception if you passed in `(2009,13,1)` or `(2009,1,32)` as well. You need to pass in values that make a valid date. If you have a question about some issue with your code ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

The following code shows how to create date values from year and month (integer) values:

```
SELECT  DATEADD(
            month,
            DATEDIFF( month, 0, GETDATE() )
                + x.[month]
                - MONTH( GETDATE() ),
            DATEADD(
                year,
                DATEDIFF( year, 0, GETDATE() )
                    + x.[year]
                    - YEAR( GETDATE() ),
                0 ) )
FROM (  SELECT [month] = 2, [year] = 2011
        UNION ALL
        SELECT [month] = 3, [year] = 2011
    ) x;
```

Answer (score 1):

Date values from year, month, AND day (integer) values, though maybe the inputs should be sanitized first:

```
SELECT  DATEADD(
            day,
            x.[day] - DAY(0),
            DATEADD(
                month,
                x.[month] - MONTH(0),
                DATEADD(
                    year,
                    x.[year] - YEAR(0),
                    0 ) ) )
FROM (  SELECT [month] = 2, [year] = 2011, [day] = 14
        UNION ALL
        SELECT [month] = 3, [year] = 2011, [day] = 2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT [month] = 5, [year] = 2011, [day] = 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT [month] = 7, [year] = 2011, [day] = 0
        UNION ALL
        SELECT [month] = 8, [year] = 2084, [day] = 40
        UNION ALL
        SELECT [month] = 1, [year] = 1940, [day] = -6
    ) x;
```

Answer (score 0):

More example code to create date values from year and month (integer) values, but even simpler than some other example code:

```
SELECT  DATEADD(
            month,
            x.[month] - MONTH(0),
            DATEADD(
                year,
                x.[year] - YEAR(0),
                0 ) )
FROM (  SELECT [month] = 2, [year] = 2011
        UNION ALL
        SELECT [month] = 3, [year] = 2011
        UNION ALL
        SELECT [month] = 5, [year] = 2011
        UNION ALL
        SELECT [month] = 7, [year] = 2011
        UNION ALL
        SELECT [month] = 8, [year] = 2084
        UNION ALL
        SELECT [month] = 1, [year] = 1940
    ) x;
```