# Meaning of CAST('1/1' + ...... as DATETIME)?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In the following T-SQL Code:

```
wt.clsdt_date >= CAST('1/1/' + CAST(2011 - 1 AS varchar) AS DateTime)
```

what does '1/1' mean?

Comment: While I appreciate all of the advice concerning the best way to write the above Code, I'm afraid I cannot do anything about how it is written, no matter how convoluted it may be.  I have no access to the code to make the appropriate changes.  I am merely trying to translate it into LINQ to SQL from a Word Document.  However, your explanations have been very helpful in explaining exactly what is going on and for that I thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Please see the other answers for improvements to the SQL.)

`'1/1/'` is string so the resulting string after the `+` is `'1/1/year'`, e.g.

```
   '1/1/' + CAST(2011 - 1 as varchar)
-> '1/1/' + '2010'
-> '1/1/2010'
```

which is then cast (converted, really) to the appropriate type.

I would be surprised if there is not a prettier method to do this.

For SQL Server 2008 and before [there does not appear to be a particularly nice standard method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266924/create-a-date-with-t-sql).

For SQL Server 2012 there is `DATEFROMPARTS` as shown in [this related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772866/how-to-create-dates-from-date-components-in-sql-t-sql):

```
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(@Year, @Month, @Day)
```

Comment: Note that [`DATEFROMPARTS`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213228.aspx) is new in SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 3):

A much safer way to do this is:

```
WHERE wt.clsdt_date >= CONVERT(CHAR(4), 2011 - 1) + '0101';
```

You don't need to explicitly cast it to a `datetime`, but you can:

```
WHERE wt.clsdt_date >= CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(4), 2011 - 1) + '0101');
```

This uses a non-regional date format and also still makes use of an index on the column, if one exists.

Also [`varchar` without length is a bad habit.](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: +1 Although '1/1/yyyy' should be "safe" in *this particular case*? I am not arguing against this approach, mind.

Comment: @pst the point is people might learn from the `1/1/` example and assume it is also safe for `6/15/` (which can yield an error) or even worse `6/7/` which could lead to wrong results but go undetected.

Comment: Yes, I agree entirely, this is a much better habit/way to write it. I was just wondering if it could affect this particular string input.

Answer (score 2):

This technique is used to evaluate whether or not wt.clsdt_date is during or after the year 2010.  The cleaner way to accomplish this would be as follows:

```
YEAR(wt.clsdt_date) >= 2010
```

Comment: That is not sargable. Wrapping the column with the `YEAR` function means an index can't be used.

Comment: @MartinSmith Lame, I would expect the planner to be able to do some deductions there...

Comment: @pst - Mostly it doesn't even when in principle it could. [There is a request to extend the cases where it does here](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/526431/make-more-functions-sargable)

Comment: @MartinSmith - It appears to be closed

Comment: @Lamak that doesn't mean that it won't be considered later if you vote and add comments. :-) Unfortunately "closed" in this context really means "closed at least for the current release."

Comment: @AaronBertrand I had already voted on that, and forgot about it till now. Too bad it won't be considered to this release